# Getting ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on ng serve command

Tags: compiler-errors, angular5

I am new to Angular and trying to set up an existing project on my machine locally. The system has windows 10. I have `npm install` and when I run `ng serve` command to compile the project then I am getting an error of `ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Here is the screenshot of the cmd

[image]

Here is my angular.json.cli file code:

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "reposee"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "repo",
      "styles": [
        "scss/styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css",
        "../node_modules/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "scss"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "www3-prod": "environments/environment.www3-prod.ts",
        "reposerver": "environments/environment.reposerver.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss"
  }
}
```

The same thing if i setup on a Linux system it works fine.

Can anyone suggest me how I can fix this issue?